# Timeout on MongoDB connection with error getaddrinfo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database and have a backend endpoint that writes data into a collection in my database. This is the code I have written up:

```
app.post('/database', async (req, res) => {
    const uri = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<clusterName>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    client.connect(err => {
        const collection = client.db('boxingvids').collection('reviewsandcomments');
        const data = {
            vidKey: 'vidKey',
            footWork: 'footWork',
            headMovement: 'head',
            punchForm: 'punchForm',
            overallRating: 'overall',
            shouldWorkOn: 'should',
            doesWell: 'doesWell',
            addComments: 'addComments'
        };
        collection.insertOne(data, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Data inserted successfully')
            client.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming I am entering the correct username and password, I am getting this error and not sure what to make of it:

```
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND scope787
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\jasmi\boxingtrainingapp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'leidoscope69:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'scope787:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 22523108,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND scope787
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\jasmi\boxingtrainingapp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jasmi\boxingtrainingapp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND scope787
              at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
            errno: -3008,
            code: 'ENOTFOUND',
            syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
            hostname: 'scope787'
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
```

My password does have an '@' sign. I am specifically looking to write into a collection, this is where it appears:

```
clusterName: programmingchallenges
database: boxingvids
collection: reviewsandcomments
```

Comment: The error message says `hostname: 'scope787'`. Is that what you expect for your MongoDB server?